# Python: Merge sub-product of multiple lists of different length into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I am trying to merge a sub-product of multiple lists of different length into a list of tuples using the following approach:

```
import itertools

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
symbols = ['*', '#', '+']
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

tuples_of_two = zip(letters, symbols)
tuples_of_three = list(itertools.product(tuples_of_two, numbers))

print(tuples_of_three)
```

which yields a list of tuples containing tuples and numbers:

```
[(('a', '*'), 1),
 (('a', '*'), 2),
 (('a', '*'), 3),
 (('a', '*'), 4),
 (('a', '*'), 5),
 (('b', '#'), 1),
 (('b', '#'), 2),
 (('b', '#'), 3),
 (('b', '#'), 4),
 (('b', '#'), 5),
 (('c', '+'), 1),
 (('c', '+'), 2),
 (('c', '+'), 3),
 (('c', '+'), 4),
 (('c', '+'), 5)]
```

But actually I am trying to obtain the following result which is a list of tuples without "sub-tuples":

```
[('a', '*', 1),
 ('a', '*', 2),
 ('a', '*', 3),
 ('a', '*', 4),
 ('a', '*', 5),
 ('b', '#', 1),
 ('b', '#', 2),
 ('b', '#', 3),
 ('b', '#', 4),
 ('b', '#', 5),
 ('c', '+', 1),
 ('c', '+', 2),
 ('c', '+', 3),
 ('c', '+', 4),
 ('c', '+', 5)]
```

Not that in the tuples I only want 'a' combined with '*', 'b' with '#' and 'c' with '+' so it is not the full product which could be reached by intertools.product.

This can probably be achieved by using some list coprehension that "untuples" the first element of the tuples or also more elegant on the direct way.

But I am stuck at the moment..

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[(letters[i], symbols[i], n) for i,n in itertools.product(range(len(letters)), numbers)]`

Comment: `flatten_tuple = lambda (nested, outer_scalar): nested + (outer_scalar,)`, just in case.

Comment: "I'm not convinced that that's really what you want. Do you really want a only combined with *? Not with # or +?" I do not want it with # or + as explained. @Stefan Pochmann: Did you now downvote because my reaction time wasn't quick enough?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! This saved my day.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann: Could you please upvote, again!? I guess the question is of value as I haven't found anything on this on SO.

Comment: I have clarified my question: "I only want 'a' combined with '*', 'b' with '#' and 'c' with '+' so it is not the full product which could be reached by intertools.product." Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's good. Also makes clear that you're aware that intertools.product could do the whole job otherwise. Wasn't clear whether you knew that. Btw, I remembered another reason I found it unclear: the "..." at the end. That made me think that maybe the combinations like 'a' with '#' would come later, in that "...". Would be an odd order, but really it looked like you just took what you had and blindly removed parentheses, so I couldn't trust that. Providing the full list would've been clearer and also useful for testing (because then we can easily compare our own results to yours with `==`).

Comment: Good point (providing full expected results). I have adjusted my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` does the same thing as a nested for loop. You can use a straight list comprehension with `zip` to achieve what you need in one go:

```
[(l, s, n) for l, s in zip(letters, symbols) for n in numbers]

#[('a', '*', 1),
# ('a', '*', 2),
# ('a', '*', 3),
# ('a', '*', 4),
# ('a', '*', 5),
# ('b', '#', 1),
# ...
```

Comment: Your answer basically reduced my code by approx. 60 %. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the tuples by building a new one that adds the inner one to a singleton tuple:

```
tuples_of_three =  [x+(y,) for x, y in itertools.product(tuples_of_two, numbers)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I went for Psidoms answer because I do not even need intertools. But yours works nicely as well!

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from `itertools.product()` documentation:

> product(A, B) returns the same as:  ((x,y) for x in A for y in B)

Hence, you could do this:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
symbols = ['*', '#', '+']
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print([(letter, symbol, number) for letter, symbol in zip(letters, symbols) for number in numbers])
```

Comment: This is a nice solution and identical with Psidoms!

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat "general" solution, using `zip(numbers)` to wrap the numbers in tuples as well. Then you uniformly only have tuples, and they can simply be summed.

```
>>> if 1:
    import itertools, pprint

    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    symbols = ['*', '#', '+']
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    zips = zip(letters, symbols), zip(numbers)

    result = [sum(p, ()) for p in itertools.product(*zips)]

    pprint.pprint(result)


[('a', '*', 1),
 ('a', '*', 2),
 ('a', '*', 3),
 ('a', '*', 4),
 ('a', '*', 5),
 ('b', '#', 1),
 ('b', '#', 2),
 ('b', '#', 3),
 ('b', '#', 4),
 ('b', '#', 5),
 ('c', '+', 1),
 ('c', '+', 2),
 ('c', '+', 3),
 ('c', '+', 4),
 ('c', '+', 5)]
>>>
```

That also works for more complicated combinations, you just need to define them, for example:

```
    zips = zip(letters, symbols), zip(numbers), zip(symbols, letters, numbers)
```

If you had much more/longer tuples, it might be more efficient to *chain* them instead:

```
    result = [tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(p))
              for p in itertools.product(*zips)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tuples_of_three = list(itertools.product(letters, symbols, numbers))
```

It should work for you:

```
('a', '*', 1)
('a', '*', 2)
('a', '*', 3)
('a', '*', 4)
('a', '*', 5)
('a', '#', 1)
('a', '#', 2)
('a', '#', 3)
('a', '#', 4)
('a', '#', 5)
('a', '+', 1)
('a', '+', 2)
('a', '+', 3)
('a', '+', 4)
('a', '+', 5)
('b', '*', 1)
('b', '*', 2)
('b', '*', 3)
('b', '*', 4)
('b', '*', 5)
('b', '#', 1)
('b', '#', 2)
...
```

Comment: I guess this is what the OP really wants, @StefanPochmann comment is spot on, does he really want `a` only combined with `*` and not with `#` or `+`?

Comment: Not with # and + so the answer is not exactly what I am looking for. Thanks anyway!